# 7zip on command line: can I use both include and exclude switches?

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip

Here's my directory structure (in Windows 8.1):

```
parentdir\
    child1\
    child2\
        grandchild1\
        grandchild2\
        grandchild3\
        ...
    child3\
    child4\
    ...
```

Using 7-Zip on commandline, I am trying to automate a compression script to archive all the content of `parentdir` into parentdir.zip.

In the resulting archive, I need to exclude all the content of `child2` except `grandchild1`.

I could have gone for:

```
7z a -r parentdir.zip parentdir\* -xr!child2\grandchild2 -xr!child2\grandchild3, etc.
```

Problem is there may be any number of grandchildren!

Again, I toyed with something like:

```
7z a -r parentdir.zip parentdir\* -xr!child2\* -ir!child2\grandchild1\*
```

The command ran nicely, completely ignoring my second (include) switch.

So, can I actually use both include and exclude switches on the same line? If yes, how? And if not, how can I achieve the goal I just described above, on my directory tree?

Thank you.

Comment: In this case these `-x` and `-i` switches contradict each other, so you could do `7z a -r parentdir.zip -ir!parentdir\child2\grandchild1\ ` from _parent_ of your `parentdir`. If your directory structure vary every now and then so you would have to change your script often, then you could do it using results of the `for` command. Start with `for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /ad /s /B parentdir') do @echo %G` for first look.